# how to show the content of one drop down dynamically on changing the value of another drop down in smarty

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I'm new to php and open to any kind of suggestions regarding this issue...

I have a nested php array something like this....

category1->0->name
category1->1->name

category2->0->name
category2->1->name
**......................

......................**

I want to show 2 drop downs in smarty template file.

first one is a category drop down i.e. category1, category2.
second one is dependent on first. So, if I select category1 in first drop down then it should show me all the **names** associated with category1 and so on....

I am not using Jquery, instead I'm working with just javascript.

**Can anyone please provide me sample code to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--JAVASCRIPT-->
<!--CREATE DROPBOX WHEN CAT1 IS SELECTED-->
<script>
var category = document.getElementById("category").value;
if(category == CAT1){
document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML='
  <select name="subcategory" type="text" id="subcategory">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Sub1">Sub1</option>
  <option value="Sub2">Sub2</option>
  <option value="Sub3">Sub3</option>
  </select>"
';
}


</script>
<!--HTML MARKUP-->

<select name="category" type="text" id="category">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="CAT1">CAT1</option>
      <option value="CAT2">CAT2</option>
      <option value="CAT3">CAT3</option>
      </select>

<!--SPACE TO PLACE DROPBOX FROM JAVASCRIPT-->
<span id="subcat">

</span>
```